# How to do stepwise regression forward correctly?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, stepwise-regression

My understanding is that you add only one single variable at a time based on various model fit or statistical criterion.  Someone advances that there is merit to running a stepwise regression by adding 3 variables at a time to see which ones survive.  I identify several problems with this approach: 1) by adding variables together you are much more likely to run into multicollinearity issues; 2) when you add just one variable at a time, you can readily identify what is the very next best variable to add to your model.  When you add three at a time, you can't tell that; 3) by adding three variables at a time, it is a lot more likely that your earlier variables that you selected with supporting economic theory and logic will get kicked out.  In other words, by using or checking for 3 variables at a time in every single step of the stepwise regression you may deconstruct or dismantle your model as you are trying to build it.  I personally do not see any redeeming circumstance to this strange procedure.  Also, do you know of a good source or a good paper explaining the basic stepwise forward regression process.  That's so it is not just me saying how this procedure should be done, but a reference with the proper credentials.

Comment: How about not using stepwise selection at all?

Comment: Your post seems to attempt to advance an argument -- with a conclusion -- rather than ask a question. An argument for entering one variable in place of three is not a suitable form for a question. As it stands this reads more like a forum post, but this isn't a forum. If you wish this to be here, please edit to make your post into a real question rather than advancing a thesis.

Comment: Glen, I see it a bit differently.  I ask a straightforward question.  "How do you do stepwise regression forward correctly?"  I then do share a debate with someone about the issue to provide framework and guide the answer.  I could have maybe presented this differently by just asking the question.  And, then separately answer my own question as an actual "answer."  I find the latter scenario a bit confusing if not arrogant.  If you answer your own question, why ask the question.  In any case, if you want to edit my debate you are welcome.

Comment: I essentially share with the audience how I understand stepwise regression forward works.  And, I share how someone else believes it works.  I advance several problems with his version of stepwise.  I invite anyone to clarify and correct me if my assessment on the subject is off.  I also would be grateful if anyone can cite or refer to a paper on the subject that would close this debate.

Comment: The [Stata documentation for `stepwise`](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rstepwise.pdf) contains a particularly pithy and clear account of the algorithms, with references.

Comment: whuber, the Stata documentation was interesting.  However, the explaining of their algorithm/coding was not entirely clear to me.  They indicated they would add one variable at a time X1 then X2.  That is convergent with everything I know about forward stepwise.  Then, they indicated they would for some reason add later X4 & X5.  This did not make sense to me.  And, it did not clearly settle the debate I fleshed out.  Most of the papers are behind paywalls.  But, through the STATA link I did find a paper written by a team of statisticians at STATA that was helpful.

Comment: Although, all above comments have been informative and some of them have provided me good leads; I still look forward to a clear answer to my question and the related settling of the debate I have on the issue with someone else.  I think I bring strong points to close the debate.  And, I am seeking confirmation that I am either correct or not.